# error during installing phoenix framework

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

Trying out phoenix and Elixir for the first time. Stuck at the very end while running the project.

```
mix phoenix.server
```

Anyone had the same problem? Here is error trace. (postgrex was added as a dependency)

** (Mix) Could not start application blog: Blog.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Blog.Repo
    ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
        ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
            ** (RuntimeError) could not find Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.

Please verify you have added :postgrex as a dependency:

```
{:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"}
```

And remember to recompile Ecto afterwards by cleaning the current build:

```
mix deps.clean ecto

            (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:420: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.start_link/4
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:343: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:326: :supervisor.start_children/3
            (stdlib) supervisor.erl:292: :supervisor.init_children/2
            (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
            (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has been fixed in the latest ecto. Please run:

```
$ mix deps.update ecto
$ mix phoenix.server
```

And you should be all set