# Elixir phoenix error when starting server

Tags: postgresql, elixir, phoenix-framework

When I create a new app and start the phoenix web server, like so:

```
$ mix phoenix.new blog
$ cd blog
$ mix phoenix.server
```

... I get the following error:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 21-Jan-2016::21:57:19 ===
    application: logger
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary
** (Mix) Could not start application blog: Blog.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Blog.Repo
    ** (EXIT) shutdown: failed to start child: Ecto.Adapters.Postgres
        ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
            ** (RuntimeError) could not find Ecto.Adapters.Postgres.Connection.

Please verify you have added :postgrex as a dependency:

    {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"}

And remember to recompile Ecto afterwards by cleaning the current build:

    mix deps.clean ecto

                (ecto) lib/ecto/adapters/sql.ex:420: Ecto.Adapters.SQL.start_link/4
                (stdlib) supervisor.erl:343: :supervisor.do_start_child/2
                (stdlib) supervisor.erl:326: :supervisor.start_children/3
                (stdlib) supervisor.erl:292: :supervisor.init_children/2
                (stdlib) gen_server.erl:328: :gen_server.init_it/6
                (stdlib) proc_lib.erl:240: :proc_lib.init_p_do_apply/3
```

I've tried just about everything I can think of.  It seems to be related to Postgres.  I've tried using postgres 9.5.0 and 9.4.5.  I've tried using both the homebrew and the postgresapp install methods.

I'm able to connect directly to Postgres with `psql`.  And, I can effectively create a database with `mix ecto.create`.  However, `mix ecto.migrate` throws the same error.

A bit of information about my current setup:

- OS: Mac 10.10.5 Yosemite
- Postgres: 9.5.0 (postgresapp)
- Erlang: 18.2.1 (homebrew install)
- Elixir: 1.2.1 (homebrew install)
- Phoenix: 1.1.3

### EDIT:

Here is my `mix.exs` file:

```rb
defmodule Blog.Mixfile do
  use Mix.Project

  def project do
    [app: :blog,
     version: "0.0.1",
     elixir: "~> 1.0",
     elixirc_paths: elixirc_paths(Mix.env),
     compilers: [:phoenix, :gettext] ++ Mix.compilers,
     build_embedded: Mix.env == :prod,
     start_permanent: Mix.env == :prod,
     aliases: aliases,
     deps: deps]
  end

  # Configuration for the OTP application.
  #
  # Type `mix help compile.app` for more information.
  def application do
    [mod: {Blog, []},
     applications: [:phoenix, :phoenix_html, :cowboy, :logger, :gettext,
                    :phoenix_ecto, :postgrex]]
  end

  # Specifies which paths to compile per environment.
  defp elixirc_paths(:test), do: ["lib", "web", "test/support"]
  defp elixirc_paths(_),     do: ["lib", "web"]

  # Specifies your project dependencies.
  #
  # Type `mix help deps` for examples and options.
  defp deps do
    [{:phoenix, "~> 1.1.3"},
     {:phoenix_ecto, "~> 2.0"},
     {:postgrex, ">= 0.0.0"},
     {:phoenix_html, "~> 2.3"},
     {:phoenix_live_reload, "~> 1.0", only: :dev},
     {:gettext, "~> 0.9"},
     {:cowboy, "~> 1.0"}]
  end

  # Aliases are shortcut or tasks specific to the current project.
  # For example, to create, migrate and run the seeds file at once:
  #
  #     $ mix ecto.setup
  #
  # See the documentation for `Mix` for more info on aliases.
  defp aliases do
    ["ecto.setup": ["ecto.create", "ecto.migrate", "run priv/repo/seeds.exs"],
     "ecto.reset": ["ecto.drop", "ecto.setup"]]
  end
end
```

Comment: can you post your mix.exs file

Comment: @SandeshSoni I've posted it above.

Comment: Hi @ElliotLarson--actually I think this is your issue right here (must have gotten posted right before you posted your question): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953211/error-during-installing-phoenix-framework

Comment: @OnorioCatenacci Ah, sweet!  Thanks for pointing that out.  That solved my problem.  So, strange.  I swear I tried that a few hours ago... oh, well.  It's working now.